# Timestamps for messages

Tags: javascript, web, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase's database to host a real time messaging web app. I've finished the basic implementation but now want to add timestamps for users to see when messages were sent.

To add a message to a chatroom I use `firebase.push()` with the value as the sent message. I guess I'll have to switch this to `.update()` with the value as an object with the fields `message` and `time sent`.

I'm trying to figure out how to populate this `time sent`. I've heard of `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` but from what I can tell it's hard to change that into a date and time. I'm heavily considering a unix timestamp like this `var unix = Math.round(+new Date()/1000);` since this is easy to convert.

Does anybody with any experience have any tips for which direction I should take? I don't need the timestamp to be super precise, just the date, hour, and minute.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to a node, the value becomes a UNIX timestamp. See the [Firebase reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#.ServerValue) for an example how to write this:

```
var sessionsRef = firebase.database().ref('sessions');
var mySessionRef = sessionsRef.push();
mySessionRef.update({ startedAt: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP });
```

When you *read* this value, you can convert it back into a `Date` object with:

```
sessionsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var startedAt = new Date(snapshot.val().startedAt);
});
```

Comment: To be consistent I'll probably end up using this then. From what I understand this will get converted to local time on the client side, right?